# What's the maximum number of logs per transaction?

Tags: transactions, logs

I am trying to determine what data type to use for indexing transaction logs.

At least in the case of transactions per block, there is a [hard limit](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/what-is-the-number-of-transactions-in-a-block).

Is it a fixed number and is there a maximum number?

Comment: How does the data type you use for indexing logs relate to the maximum logs possible per transaction?

Comment: I need to know if log index can fit into small int. For what is is worth, based on everything I've read so far, I am pretty confident it will always do.

Answer (score 2):

There's no hard limit on LOG entries. In practice it is limited by the block gas limit and the cost of each LOG opcode.

Currently the minimum cost for a LOG is 375 (reference: https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md#a8-log-operations). In mainnet the block gas limit is 15M. So a program can generate up to 15*10^6 / 375 = 40000 log entries.

Comment: That's theoretical limit. Is it possible to hit that number in practice?

Comment: @Gajus There's no limit in theory. In practice you need to pushes 0 twice and a log0, total cost 375 + 3 + 3. For mainnet you can execute 39370.

Comment: In this case it’s simpler to calculate the theoretical limit than the “practical” one. Since the absolute limit is the theoretical one, better to work with that. You’re in luck because `log2(15 * 10^6 / 375) = 15.29`, so you’re covered with a `uint16` (in whichever language you’re using.) But who knows, the block limit could go up, and the cost of a `log0` could go up, so to be “safe” I’d go for a `uint32` and then forget about it forever.

Comment: If you want a _practical_ limit, you can’t really calculate it, but you can estimate it empirically. E.g. if you take the last couple of blocks, count the logs per block and plot the histogram of this count, you will get a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Ismael has added a good answer for your main question, so partial answer for the part about transactions per block:

The hard limit you've referred to is for Bitcoin, and it's a few years out of date.

For Ethereum, the two things to consider are:

- The current block gas limit, which is [15 Mgas](https://etherscan.io/chart/gaslimit)
- The base gas cost of an EOA -> EOA transaction (i.e. 21,000 gas)

Taking these into account, the current tx/block limit is ~714 transactions.